# Save instance layout in activities

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can implement part of layout which will beuse in three or four activities, but I want to save look this layout. I mean In first layout I add button to my part, In second Activity I will see my part with button. In second activity I add second button and in third activity I want to see both buttons, etc. I want to add this buttons in code, not xml. How I can do one instance layout for all activities which will be keep all changes added in previous activities?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could create the layout with all the buttons available - if they are only a few -, and hide the selectable ones with `android:visibility="gone"` in xml.
Later on you keep track of the selections in an internal Object or ArrayList, and change visibility for the selected buttons in each subsequent Activity's `onCreate` or `onResume`.

Another solution is to create an xml with the spare space for the additional buttons, and add them from code. In this case you have to keep track of all information about the added buttons in code, not just the states, but the theory is the same.

If you want to save the layout over application restarts as well, you will have to save that information yourself, Android does not have this built-in.

Comment: I can't do that, because I don't know how many activities will use this layout.

Comment: In that case you might want to extend a built-in layout with capabilities achieving the goal, and let all the activities use that. But in that case you still end up with the second solution. Android - as of now - does not offer easy ways to accomplish what you have written.